# Trying to redirect to another HTML page using Render Template in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to redirect to another HTML page using render_template in flask but its not responding even if the condition of if-statement is met and render_template is not getting triggered

```
@app.route('/ValidateOTP', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def ValidateOTP():
        OTP = request.get_json()
        otpinstant=session['OTPINSTA']
        if otpinstant==OTP:
            Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            s = Session()
            query = s.query(ElectricMan).filter_by(email_id=email).first()
            result=query.first_name
            if result:
                session['logged_in'] = True
                return render_template('electricprofwelcomepage.html')
                #resp = jsonify(success=True)
                #return resp

        else:
            resp = jsonify(success=False)
            return resp
```

Comment: Are you sure that both of your if statements are met and your html file is in `templates` folder?

Comment: Add some print display to check if the conditions are met. Check the session print by putting : if result: 
print(session['logged_in'])
 session['logged_in'] = True

Comment: @KostasCharitidis .. Thanks for your answer!! Yes the if statements are met and  also the html page is in the templates folder but still the render_template is not working :(

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha yes session['logged_in'] = True works i checked the same but render_template is not working still

Comment: what if you try to return some other page or text.? try return "Something" to check if its redirected and returns "Something".